# Is there a benefit to using LLVM integers having a multiple of 8 bits?

Tags: llvm

Since you can specify the number of bits in a LLVM integer is their is their any performance gain to using integers that are multiples of whole bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microprocessors perform arithmetic operations with one instruction for operands of specific size. Other cases require emulation with multiple machine instructions, which is necessarily inefficient.

For example, consider unsigned integer addition (ADD) on X86 processors: it adds two numbers of n bits producing a n+1 bit result that is split between a n bit register or memory location and the carry flag. For weird operand sizes, to emulate ADD you would have to use ADD for the next biggest supported size, then a test to see if the ADD result uses more than n bits, and some more jumps and logical operations to set the result and the carry flag correctly.